# Weird DOM loading, when rendering mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, dom

We're creating a pretty heavy site that has some pretty basic parallax scrolling.

You can see the site here: http://fochisel.dev.randomshapes.ca/

The site (which is still in development) is having some really weird issues when the viewport is below 1000px. 1000px is our breakpoint for when the parallax scrolling just becomes normal scrolling. From this point on I'm just going to call that mobile view.

So, when we do a first load in mobile view, only the DOM elements in the viewport seem to render, everything else just isn't there. I can see the elements loading in the inspector, but they seem to miss actually the actual rendering step.

I'm sure there is a pretty easy solution to this, and I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following javascript to ensure that the user is scrolled to  the top of the page regardless to the device in-use.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }); 
</script>
```